# ggplot2 creates plot background too small so some axes text is not visible, how do i fix?

Tags: r, ggplot2, formatting, axes

I am creating a line chart in ggplot and the window is too small so the last axes label on the x axes is only partly visible.

```
The data is 
Year    TM  ZE  M
2005    135 35      
2006    148 42      
2007    120 50      
2008    150 51      
2009    145 40  26
2010    175 43  42
2011    172 65  71
2012    165 75  71
2013    160 68  45
2014    142 91  50
2015    135 101 52
```

And my code is

```
gc<-c("#87B1DC", "#77aa7f", "#c64646", "#885db2","#FFAA00","#00c5dd")
g1<-ggplot(data=dat1, aes(x=Year, y =M))+
geom_line(lwd=2,col=gc[6])+
ylab("Population Size")+
theme_bw()+
scale_x_continuous(limits=c(2005,2015),breaks=c(2005,2007,2009,2011,2013,2015), expand = c(0, 0))
g1
```

But the '2015' on the x axes only is cut off by the end of the window, can anyone help me to extend the window.

I tried removing the expand argument, which solves it, but adds extra space inside the chart, I would like the 2015 to be the last point on the chart so the line reaches the end of the plot.

Many Thanks

Answer (score 1):

If you change the limits on your x-axis from

```
scale_x_continuous(limits=c(2005,2015),breaks=c(2005,2007,2009,2011,2013,2015)
```

to

```
scale_x_continuous(limits=c(2004.8,2015.2),breaks=c(2005,2007,2009,2011,2013,2015)
```

this should look a bit better. It's not the cleanest solution but it keeps the line close to the end of the graph like you wanted while still leaving the year visible

Answer (score 0):

You can change the plot margin using `plot.margin` in `theme`.  You can control all four margins.

From the documentation for `plot.margin`:

> margin around entire plot (unit with the sizes of the top, right,
>   bottom, and left margins)

You need to fill in something for each margin, making the right margin larger than the others.

For example, you could do:

```
theme(plot.margin = unit(c(.2, .5, .2, .2), "cm"))
```

Comment: @alexk Glad it helped! If it answered your question you can check the tick mark or upvote.